# Foreign keys being ommitted when I pass table struct into db.Create() on gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have the following:

```
 type Buyer struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email string
    Name string
    Password string
    Delivery_address string
}

type Seller struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email string
    Name string
    Password string
    Pickup_address string
}

type status string
const (
    pending status = "pending"
    accepted status = "accepted"
)

type Orderr struct {
    gorm.Model
    Buyer Buyer `gorm:"foreignkey:ID"`
    Seller Seller `gorm:"foreignKey:ID"`
    Delivery_source_address string
    Delivery_destination_address string
    Quantity int
    Price float32
    Total_price float32
    Status status
}

db.Transaction(func(tx *gorm.DB) error {

    buyer := Buyer{}
    db.Find(&buyer, 1)

    seller := Seller{}
    db.Find(&seller, 1)

    order := Orderr {
        Buyer: buyer,
        Seller: seller,
        Delivery_source_address: "source_address",
        Delivery_destination_address: "destiantion_address",
        Quantity: 1,
        Price: 2.00,
        Total_price: 2.00,
        Status: pending }

    db.Create(&order)

  return nil
})
```

Both the buyer and seller above return with values.

When I attempt to run db.Create(), I get the following:

ERROR: null value in column "buyer" violates not-null constraint (SQLSTATE 23502)
[2.720ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO "orderrs"
("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","delivery_source_address","delivery_destination_address","quantity","price","total_price","status") VALUES
('2021-04-27 14:37:27.519','2021-04-27 14:37:27.519',**NULL**,'source_address','destiantion_address',1,2.000000,2.000000,'pending') RETURNING "id"

The Buyer and the Seller aren't being passed for some reason.

I'm using postgresql btw

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution if anyone else is stuck on this:

```
type Orderr struct {
    gorm.Model
    Buyer Buyer `gorm:"foreignkey:ID;references:buyer_id"`
    Buyer_id uint
    Seller Seller `gorm:"foreignKey:ID;references:seller_id"`
    Seller_id uint
    Delivery_source_address string
    Delivery_destination_address string
    Quantity int
    Price float32
    Total_price float32
    Status status
}
```

DO NOT name your foreign keys the same name as the table they're referencing.